# A inside figure or figure inside a?

Tags: html, anchor, semantics, figure

Go down to the HTML part of the code snippet. The first box has a `figure` that wraps an `a` with an `img` tag. The second box has an `a` that wraps a `figure` with an `img` tag.

**Which of the boxes is the most correct one?**

Should figure wrap a or should a wrap figure?

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: .5rem;
}

img {
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 100%;
}

.text {
  padding: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<!-- A inside figure -->
<div class="box">
  <figure>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/500/500">
    </a>
  </figure>
  <div class="text">Text</div>
</div>

<!-- Figure inside a -->
<div class="box">
 <a href="#">
   <figure>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/500/500">
   </figure>
  </a>
  <div class="text">Text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked and reviewed shared HTML. also, debugged/analyzed in firebug (Firefox add-ons) Box-Model. `a` properly wrapped to `figure`.

The **second box** is correct. `a` completely properly wrapped to `figure`.

```
<!-- Figure inside a -->

<div class="box">
 <a href="#">
   <figure>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/500/500">
   </figure>
  </a>
  <div class="text">Text</div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd argue that both your variations are semantically correct, and they both validate within the HTML5 standards.

Both the `<a>` and `<figure>` tags are flow content, and permitted content inside the very same tags is *also* flow content [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content). So wrapping either one of them inside the other would make perfect sense.

If you want to link the figure contents including `<img>`, `<figcaption>` or any flow content, I'd wrap everything inside the `<a>` tag.

If you want to link just the `<img>` or any other specific element, I'd wrap everything inside the `<figure>` tag and then the anchor inside.

I'm not sure about accessibility concerns in this case, but I think it depends™ on the content.